# Program crashes when String used by StringSink goes out of scope

Tags: c++, c++14, crypto++

Today I started trying out the Cryptopp library.
I took an example from the documentation [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder).

The program crashes and I cannot seem to figure out why.

**My code:**

```
#include <cryptopp/dll.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    std::cout << "START OF PROGRAM" << std::endl;

    {
        std::string encoded;
        CryptoPP::byte decoded[] = { 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA, 0x99, 0x88, 0x77, 0x66, 0x55, 0x44, 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00 };

        //Method 1
        CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder2;
        encoder2.Attach(new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded));
        encoder2.Put(decoded, sizeof(decoded));
        encoder2.MessageEnd();

        //Method 2
        //CryptoPP::StringSource ss(decoded, sizeof(decoded), true, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)));

        std::cout << "Encoded: ";
        std::cout << encoded;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "END OF PROGRAM" << std::endl;
}
```

**The output is:**

```
START OF PROGRAM
Encoded: FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100
```

Which means that `END OF PROGRAM`is not reached, but the HexEncoder did its job as expected. As soon as my `std::string encoded;` goes out of scope the program crashes. If I move `std::string encoded;` to the outer scope (the scope of `int main(...)`) then `END OF PROGRAM` is printed and the program crashes at the end of `main`.

Also, if I don't call `encoder2.Put(...)` the program does not crash, but obviously the `HexEncoder` also does nothing. Using Method 2 instead of Method 1 results in the same error.

**The error I get is:**

```
HEAP[app.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 000001CE84480000, 000001CE84761390 )
```

**About my environment:**

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I used the VS-solution in the cryptopp source to build the library using the `DLL-Import Debug` build-config. The changed I made to the config are:

- I had to change the Runtime Library setting from `/MTd` to `/MDd` (since the larger program I'm working on and want to use cryptopp in is using `/MDd`).
- I also removed the `CRYPTOPP_ENABLE_COMPLIANCE_WITH_FIPS_140_2=1`
  preprocessor-definition since it caused issues (I think because of
  running my program in the Visual Studio debugger). I don't care about FIPS-compliance at this point.

**Other details**

Another example which involved `FileSink` which takes a `stringstream` did work as expected without the issue I described above:

```
std::stringstream encoded;
CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder2(new CryptoPP::FileSink(encoded));
encoder2.Put(decoded, sizeof(decoded));
encoder2.MessageEnd();
std::cout << encoded.str();
```

And some testing I did involving symmetric Salsa20 encryption and decryption (example from [here](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Salsa20)) did also work properly (building and running).

**Question**

Can somebody explain what goes wrong, how I can fix it or if it is a bug in the library or my building process?

Comment: `std::string encoded;` -- Reserve space before using the string: `encoded.reserve(1000);`.  Does your program crash?  If not, then this maybe an issue of the `string` using different heaps in different modules.

Comment: I tried your program and it works (after changing `CryptoPP::byte` by `byte` because otherwise it would't compile).  @PaulMcKenzie There's no need to reserve space in the `std::string`.

Comment: BTW, can you try `encoder2.Detach()` so it frees the sink?

Comment: @JuanR -- I wanted to see if the issue has to do with allocation and where the allocation is being done.  If the memory is reserved in that module, then the destruction would only free the memory that was reserved in that module, and not free memory that was allocated in another module.  I still want to see if without any changes *except* for the `reserve()`, if the program still crashes.  If it doesn't, then my suspicions point to differing heaps.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand you point but, based on the [source code](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/filters_8h_source.html), it doesn't look that's the case. I might be wrong tough, vc++ can be deceiving sometimes..

Comment: I tried already tried using `encoder2.Detach()` unfortunately with no change and the issue still occurs.

Comment: I also already tried using `encoder2.resize(1000);` which results in a runtime error inside `encoder2.Put(...)`. However, because you ask I also tried with `encoder2.reserve(1000);` which makes it work! The minimum characters to reserve is 32 which is logical since that are the number of expected hex-characters. (These tests are without the `endocer2.Detach()` line).

Comment: But why doesn't it work when I used `encoder2.resize(1000)` instead? (I did put a empty value in the string like `std::string encoded="";`).

Comment: `resize` will increase the size of the string and **fill it** with the default character. `reserve` will allocate memory but not fill it (i.e.: free to put some data on it).

Comment: That `reserve` is required should be included in the examples I referred to in my post. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I think it is not included because they do it in the [code](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/filters_8h_source.html). But the condition is wrong: `if (length < size && size + length > m_output->capacity())
  m_output->reserve(2*size); ` They will resize the string not only if the current size plus the length is greater than the capacity, but also if the length is less than size, which doesn't look well. I would report it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks! Well found! I filed a bug report with the suggestion that I think i it should be:
`if (size + length > m_output->capacity())    m_output->reserve(size + length);`.

Comment: I you want, you can create an answer for this post and I will accept it as answer ;).

Comment: Given that `reserve()` worked, it seems to be an issue of allocating memory (via adding characters to the string) in one module from one heap, and then when the string is destroyed, it is being destroyed in the "source" module, which is using a different heap.  Thus the run-time error.  Make sure you are building *all* your components with the same compiler options, runtime options, and if this is Windows, you're using the Multithreaded DLL runtime, so that all objects that cross module boundaries use the same heap.

Comment: BTW, the reserve() trick worked, since as soon as the string was created in module A, you reserved all the memory it needed in module A.  Thus module B (which I guess is where the crypto functions reside) will have no reason to fool around with the heap for the string, since the string has the memory already reserved for it.  Originally, you created an empty string, and thus the crypto module will need to reserve memory, but it's going to be module A that will be destroying the string, which will be looking at an "alien" heap allocated buffer.  This is all speculation, but a plausible guess.